# Convert a column to datetime object using different indexing methods

Tags: r, datetime

I'm trying to convert a column of dates within a dataframe to a datetime object.

```
dates <- c("11/28/2016 10:08 AM", "11/28/2016 10:08 AM", "11/28/2016 10:08 AM")
dates <- as.data.frame(dates)
# Using a $ to index the column works 
dates$dates <- as.POSIXlt(dates$dates, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
            dates
1 2016-11-28 10:08:00
2 2016-11-28 10:08:00
3 2016-11-28 10:08:00
# But this does not work
dates[,'dates'] <- as.POSIXlt(dates[,'dates'], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , "dates", value = list(sec = c(0,  :
  provided 11 variables to replace 1 variables
```

Why does one indexing method work but not the other?

I would prefer to use the latter because is this will be wrapped in a function and in the past I've had trouble indexing columns using `$` and `paste()` in functions.

Comment: Use the `[[` i.e. `dates[['dates']] <-  as.POSIXlt(dates[['dates']], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")`  as the `as.POSIXlt` is not really a vector.  You can check by `unclass(dates$dates)`

Answer (score 0):

@akrun is correct `as.POSIXlt` is not a vector and cannot be simply added as a column to the dataframe. For lists, `[[` is used to select a single element, whereas `[` returns a list of the selected elements.

```
dates[['dates']] <- as.POSIXlt(dates[['dates']], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
            dates
1 2016-11-28 10:08:00
2 2016-11-28 10:08:00
3 2016-11-28 10:08:00
```